# Understanding numbers given in OutOfMemoryError: Required array length

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory, java-11

We are running a Java program provided by a third party which reads data from the database and processes it. However, the execution fails with an error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Required array length 1313719368 + 1313719368 is too large
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport.hugeLength(ArraysSupport.java:649)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport.newLength(ArraysSupport.java:642)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:678)
```

What do the numbers in `1313719368 + 1313719368` refer to? Does this mean it tries to allocate 2,627,438,736 elements, crosses some kind of maximum array length, and fails? If so, what determines the maximum array length?

Comment: Surely you know the size of the array you tried to allocate?

Comment: "*Does it mean it tries to allocate 2,627,438,736 elements? Now since it crosses the maximum array length, it fails?*" --> yes! yes!

Comment: The full stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryError` would almost certainly point to exactly how this is failing.  Can you please include it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `OutOfMemoryError` is being thrown by the internal JDK class [`jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/blob/9d8ad2ed62325bd8d813974d5aa1e031ed8bf8da/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/ArraysSupport.java#L650).

```java
    private static int hugeLength(int oldLength, int minGrowth) {
        int minLength = oldLength + minGrowth;
        if (minLength < 0) { // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError(
                "Required array length " + oldLength + " + " + minGrowth + " is too large");
        } else if (minLength <= SOFT_MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
            return SOFT_MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH;
        } else {
            return minLength;
        }
    }
```

This method is called by the public JDK-internal method `ArraysSupport.newLength`, which explains its purpose and this exception behavior in its Javadoc comment:

> Computes a new array length given an array's current length, a minimum growth amount, and a preferred growth amount. The computation is done in an overflow-safe fashion.
>
> This method is used by objects that contain an array that might need to be grown in order to fulfill some immediate need (the minimum growth amount) but would also like to request more space (the preferred growth amount) in order to accommodate potential future needs.
>
> […]
>
> If the minimum required length exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE, then this method throws OutOfMemoryError.

A search in my IDE against the Java 21 library finds a number of different locations in the JDK that call `ArraysSupport.newLength`, including `ArrayList`, `FileInputStream`, and `AbstractStringBuilder`.  In your case, the stack trace tells us that this is happening within [`ArrayList.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) by its internal private method `ArrayList.grow`.

What this tells me is that the third-party program is performing some operation that results in the `ArrayList` class needing to allocate an array larger than the maximum array length supported by Java.  The rest of the stack trace would likely show what part of the third-party triggered the JDK call that resulted in the error.

To answer your question about whether it "tries to allocate 2,627,438,736 elements" and fails due to exceeding the maximum array length, that's close to what's happening here.  To be more precise, the code checks whether an array of the given summed length is legal to create, or whether would exceed the maximum legal array length ([`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)).  If the array length would be too long, it fails rather than attempting to create an array of the invalid length.  In particular, the third party code is attempting to add items to an `ArrayList` that would increase its size past `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Side note: it’s suspicious that both, the old length and the required growth, are exactly 1313719368 elements. This looks like the software is doing something like `list.addAll(list)`…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it means exactly that. It tries to allocate 2,627,438,736 elements and that is way more that the maximum allowed 2,147,483,647 in Java array.